# Networking server/client library to setup p2p connection

Tags: networking

I'm making a multiplayer game, and I want to setup a p2p network.
I'm coding a server in python to make the matches and send each player it's adversary ip and port, but I'm having trouble to make udp hole punching to work.
On the client side I'm using ENET library that works over UDP.
Is there any library specific for game networking that will include all necesary from making the match to setup the p2p?

Answer (score 2):

There is a big problem for the P2P: the NAT curse. Peer to peer is difficult because a lot of client are connected through NAT.

If you are interested in lan play, broadcasting may be a solution (do not try to cheat by Faking a LAN throught a VPN...)

A good alternative may be linjingle: a library developed by google to allow audio/video in XMPP sessions (you may know XMPP as Jabber Istant Messaging).

In this case you have to setup a Jabber server and extend it to provide gaming functionalities, then write the client using jingle to allow them to exchange their data.

Answer (score 1):

You need a solution that will do the firewall penetration for you.  In general, this is called STUN:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

No matter what, you will need your users to all talk to a single server that they can all see at least once to find each other, and help poke through each others firewalls.  If you want to blow the money on bandwidth, it's certainly simpler if that server also reflects their traffic for them.

This appears to be an open source implementation, although I haven't used it:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/

If you make your game with Steamworks on PC, I believe their p2p matchmaking will do the hard work for you.